# Heroku prevents direct access of subroutes in Angular

Tags: angular, heroku, routes

I deployed a MEAN stack app onto Heroku with URL mean-app.herokuapp.com. In my local testing environment, I can directly access http://localhost:4200/login page without needing to go through http://localhost:4200/ navigation to login. However, I cannot do the same in production. When I try to directly access https://mean-app.herokuapp.com/login, it gives me the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I access the subroutes of the deployed webapp directly after deploying to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

This link (https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) describes exactly the problem that I am having, and it offers a general solution for the problem, but not specific enough for my case.

There is actually a solution here (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2885) where all you have to do is to change

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

into this

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```